# Nodejs not waiting for async function to execute first in app.js

Tags: node.js

I want to retrieve my JWT key from AWS secrets and then run passport.js which will load the key.

```
// app.js
// Retrieve secrets from AWS
(async () => {
  console.log("Retrieving AWS Secrets");
  await awsSecretManager.getAllSecrets();
})();

require('./components/auth/passport.js');
```

However, before getAllSecrets function is completed, passport.js has already executed. Can be verified as there is a log that I had written in the file.

```
const getAllSecrets = async () => {
    try {
        // DB Prod/Dev Secret
        const dbProdSecrets = await getSecretValue("db");
        process.env.RDS_HOST = dbProdSecrets.SecretString.host;
        process.env.RDS_USER = dbProdSecrets.SecretString.username
        process.env.RDS_PASSWORD = dbProdSecrets.SecretString.password
        process.env.RDS_DATABASE = "database"

        // JWT Secret
        const jwtSecret = await getSecretValue("jwt");
        process.env.JWT_SECRET = jwtSecret.SecretString.JWT_SECRET;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: async functions acts inside synchron but not fot the outside world

Comment: await does not stop the async function from being async in the first place. await works only inside async not globally, so the solution is to rewrite the code to load passport only after getAllSecrets is completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather wait for everything to finish up before starting the server

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = async () => {
    // fetching secrets from aws secrets
    await awsSecretManager.getAllSecrets();
    // on fetching success
    // ... doing other imports
    require('./components/auth/passport.js');
    // configuring my server
    app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
        return res.send("hello");
    });
    // start the server finally
    app.listen(5000, () => console.log("okk"));
};
server();
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you run app.js your Immediately Invoked Function expression runs and it is fetching AllSecrets in the background while your passport file is also run. You need to wait for it. So place the require after fetching Secrets

```
// app.js
// Retrieve secrets from AWS
(async () => {
  console.log("Retrieving AWS Secrets");
  await awsSecretManager.getAllSecrets();
  require('./components/auth/passport.js');
})();
```